# Change value of input and submit form in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onclick, submit

I'm currently working on a basic form. When you hit the submit button, it should first change the value of a field, and then submit the form as usual. It all looks a bit like this:

```
<form name="myform" id="myform" action="action.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="myinput" value="0" />
    <input type="text" name="message" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="DoSubmit()" />
</form>
```

And this is how far I've come with the JavaScript code. It changes "myinput"'s value to 1, but it does not submit the form.

```
function DoSubmit(){
  document.myform.myinput.value = '1';
  document.getElementById("myform").submit();
}
```

Comment: why not just change myinput value to 1 in the html?

Comment: of course i could do that, but if thats what i wanted i woulden't have asked about it

Comment: @Paparappa That response killed it!

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You could do something like this instead:

```
<form name="myform" action="action.php" onsubmit="DoSubmit();">
    <input type="hidden" name="myinput" value="0" />
    <input type="text" name="message" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

And then modify your DoSubmit function to just return true, indicating that "it's OK, now you can submit the form" to the browser:

```
function DoSubmit(){
  document.myform.myinput.value = '1';
  return true;
}
```

I'd also be wary of using onclick events on a submit button; the order of events isn't immediately obvious, and your callback won't get called if the user submits by, for example, hitting return in a textbox.

Comment: No, you can access forms and their child elements using their `name` attributes like this.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that onclick events are not triggered when submitting by other means than pressing the button itself.

Answer (score 7):

```
document.getElementById("myform").submit();
```

This won't work as your form tag doesn't have an id.

Change it like this and it should work:

```
<form name="myform" id="myform" action="action.php">
```

Comment: oh it has an ID, im sorry was just a little quick in my coding. edited the previous post.

Answer (score 7):

Here is simple code. You must set an id for your input. Here call it 'myInput':

```
var myform = document.getElementById('myform');
myform.onsubmit = function(){
    document.getElementById('myInput').value = '1';
    myform.submit();
};
```

Answer (score 5):

No. When your input type is submit, you should have an `onsubmit` event declared in the markup and then do the changes you want. Meaning, have an `onsubmit` defined in your form tag.

Otherwise change the input type to a button and then define an `onclick` event for that button.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to access an element based on the `name` attribute which works for postbacks to the server, but JavaScript responds to the `id` attribute. Add an `id` with the same value as `name` and all should work fine.

```
<form name="myform" id="myform" action="action.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="myinput" id="myinput" value="0" />
  <input type="text" name="message" id="message" value="" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" onclick="DoSubmit()" />
</form>

function DoSubmit(){
  document.getElementById("myinput").value = '1';
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem turned out to be that I was assigning as `document.getElementById("myinput").Value = '1';`

Notice the capital V in Value? Once I changed it to small case, i.e., *value*, the data started posting. Odd as it was not giving any JavaScript errors either.

Comment: Why would it give an error? You're creating a new property "Value", which is perfectly fine.

Comment: What I am trying to say is i was referring to "value" as "Value". It of course will give a undefined error as this property "Value" was not initialized

Comment: Well, it would: 1) Give no error if you're setting it, 2) Silently return `undefined` if you're using it, which is not an error.

Comment: You are right..I should have clarified a bit more.. I was assigning a "Value" property and posting a form. The POST received in the the server was looking for "value" and hence never found the value I was setting

Answer (score 1):

I have done this and it works for me.
At first you must add a script such as my SetHolderParent() and call in the html code like below.

```js
function SetHolderParent(value) {
   alert(value);
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="SetHolderParent(222);" />
```

Comment: Please don't provide code-only answers - it is very hard to understand stuff when it isn't explained.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **onchange** event:

```
<form name="myform" id="myform" action="action.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="myinput" value="0" onchange="this.form.submit()"/>
    <input type="text" name="message" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="DoSubmit()" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

#### Your HTML

```html
<form id="myform" action="action.php">
<input type="hidden" name="myinput" value="0" />
<input type="text" name="message" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="save()" />
</form>
```

#### Your Script

```js
    <script>
        function save(){
            $('#myinput').val('1');
            $('#form').submit();
        }
    </script>
```