# How to Intercept and Modify / Alter a Django Request URL?

Tags: django, django-urls, django-request

I have a search box.

I search for:                  <- blank spaces in my search box.

My form validation catches this.

[image: url posts blanks]

The URL shows: `++++++++++++++++`

If I search for: `<script>alert(1);</script>`

[image: another search]

The URL shows: `<script>alert%281%29%3B<%2Fscript>`

#### The Question

Where in Django can I alter / change / modify the request that determines the request URL? I'm thinking middleware but I haven't found an example. Would I have to create an entirely new `HttpRequest` from scratch?

#### Why do I want to?

I want to encode the URL differently. For example, strip all punctuation from the `q=` value, replace whitespace, strip, replace single spaces with `+` to have cleaner URLs.

Really looking for a clear example with CODE.

Comment: This is how you send form data in a HTTP get request with content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded. It's defined in the HTTP standard. It's not something django specific. The url is created in the browser according to the http standard.

Comment: If you don't like the standard behaviour (which is the same as used in stackoverflow search, google search etc.) I think the simplest option is to use javascript and change the form's onsubmit handler. You can replace unwanted characters before submitting the query. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912197/change-value-of-input-and-submit-form-in-javascript

Comment: onsubmit visibly changes the input's value right before submitting - a behavior I do not want.

Comment: That can be avoided. For example you can create a clone of the form with cloneNode, change the query value there and submit the clone form. If you need help with that, you can ask a new question using the javascript tag. There might be simpler solutions too. You could probably just change `window.location.search` to the query you want. That should be equivalent to submitting the form.