# How to check Django's automatic form validation result before javascript submit

Tags: javascript, django, forms

I'm working on an advanced search page of a Django (3.2) project.  I'm using pure javascript and Django's formset_factory to create a dynamic form where the user can create a hierarchy of forms containing advanced search criteria (for and/or groups).  It works great.  However...

Early on during development, before I wrote the javascript to pass the additional hierarchy information to `views.py`'s `form_valid` method, Django (without me adding any specific code to do so) was performing nice form validation before submit and would present a nice tooltip that pointed to missing form fields, and the form (desirably) would not submit:

[image: Advanced hierarchical search form(s) from an earlier version of my project. Ignore the debug "Query was empty" output]

When I implemented the javascript to save the hierarchy information, attached to a listener on the submit button, I noticed that the tooltip would appear for a fraction of a second and the invalid form would inappropriately submit.  Here's the code that was introduced that inadvertently bypassed Django's automatic form validation:

```
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
            appendInnerSearchQuery(document.querySelector('.hierarchical_search'), 0, rootGroup);

            var myform = document.getElementById("hierarchical_search_form");
            document.getElementById("advanced_search_submit").addEventListener("click", function () {
                saveSearchQueryHierarchy(document.querySelector('.hierarchical_search'));
                myform.submit();
            });
        });
        
        console.log("Ready with rootGroup: ", rootGroup);
    </script>
```

In fact, subsequent efforts appear to submit even before the tooltip has a chance to show up, presumably due to the time it takes to validate, and the form is submitted before Django's automatic form validation has completed.

I understand **why** this breaks/overrides Django's automatic form validation.  What I have been trying to figure out is:

1. How do I (in javascript) wait for Django's automatic form validation to complete?
2. How do I check the result of the form validation in javascript, so I can decide whether or not to call `myform.submit()`?

I have been googling this for a couple days now and cannot find anything that tells me how to, in javascript, retrieve Django's automatic form validation result.  Everything I have found addresses validating in javascript from scratch.  I would rather use Django's automatic validation mechanisms, so I can specify them in the class I created in `forms.py`.

Comment: You should listen for the form's submit event instead of the button click. If validation fails then the submit event will be prevented

Comment: @IainShelvington Will that allow me to manipulate the values in the form? I.e. will the changes I make to the values of hidden form fields be reflected in the submitted data?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/6912264/548562

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes, it looks like that should do what I want. I'll try this out later today & follow up here. So to summarize: I listen for the form's submit event to trigger Django's automatic form validation. If it validates, a submit event occurs, & I can use `onsubmit` to call `saveSearchQueryHierarchy`. I might have some issues. I was just looking at the latest code, & I noted that it changes the element IDs (to replace `__prefix__` with a form index) to match what Django expects. But maybe I can split up the work & do that on click and edit values on submit. Not sure that's necessary.

Comment: I know it's been awhile, but I just tried your suggestion @IainShelvington. The form still inappropriately submits. Must be something else going on...